# Why is this map not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of `associado`, and I want to select only the ones where `eh_proprietario` returns `true`. This is the mapping:

```
@possiveis_associados = associados.map { |e| e if e.eh_proprietario}
```

If I add a `puts "#{e.eh_proprietario}"` I can see it return true for two instances, but in my view, when I try to use this collection, I get an error because `@possiveis_associados` is nil.

```
<%= m.select :associado_id , options_from_collection_for_select(@possiveis_associados, :id, :razao_social), {include_blank: false}, {class: 'form-control'}%>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `select`, not `map`. Try

```
@possiveis_associados = associados.select { |e| e.eh_proprietario }
```

or, shorter

```
@possiveis_associados = associados.select(&:eh_proprietario)
```

Comment: Can select be used with a negation? Like `.select(&:!eh_proprietario)`?

Comment: Use `reject` for that. `associados.reject(&:eh_proprietario)`